# How to make a custom character on a TFT LCD display? (128x128)

Tags: arduino-nano, display, tft

I'm currently using the ucglib library. I'm new to arduino and I'm wanting to simply display a lcd smiley I made with the byte generator. I still have some of the original 'font hello world' stuff down the bottom but I'm curious how to make my character work.

I want to make different smileys in different colours but I'm unsure how to go about this as every guide is on a 16x2 lcd and not a tft one. I have an arduino nano that is just hooked up to that lcd display. I'm going to make pressing buttons change the smiley after I've figured out how to actually put a smiley into it. Hope someone can help.

```
 * LED =   3.3V
 * SCK =   13
 * SDA =   11
 * A0 =    8
 * RESET = 9
 * CS =    10
 * GND =   GND
 * VCC =   5V

    #include "Ucglib.h"  // Include Ucglib library to drive the display


// Create display and define the pins:
Ucglib_ST7735_18x128x160_HWSPI ucg(8, 10, 9);






int smiley = byte customChar[] = {
  B00000,
  B01010,
  B01010,
  B00000,
  B10001,
  B10001,
  B11111,
  B00000
};  






void setup(void)  // Start of setup
{

  //ucg.begin(UCG_FONT_MODE_TRANSPARENT);  // It doesn't overwrite background, so it's a mess for text that changes
  ucg.begin(UCG_FONT_MODE_SOLID);  // It writes a background for the text. This is the recommended option

  ucg.clearScreen();  // Clear the screen

  ucg.setRotate180();  // Put 90, 180 or 270, or comment to leave default


  ucg.setColor(0, 255, 255, 255);  // Set color (0,R,G,B)
  ucg.setColor(1, 0, 0, 0);  // Set color of text background (1,R,G,B)
  ucg.setPrintPos(0,24);  // Set position (x,y)
  ucg.print("Welcome");  // Print text or value



  // Draw smiley:
  ucg.setColor(0, 255, 255);  // Set color (0,R,G,B)
  ucg.drawFrame(0, 58, 60, 30);  // Start from top-left pixel (x,y,wigth,height)




void loop(void)  // Start of loop
{

  Variable1++;  // Increase variable by 1
  if(Variable1 > 150)  // If Variable1 is greater than 150
  {
    Variable1 = 0;  // Set Variable1 to 0
  }



  // Convert Variable1 into a string, so we can change the text alignment to the right:
  // It can be also used to add or remove decimal numbers.
  char string[10];  // Create a character array of 10 characters
  // Convert float to a string:
  dtostrf(Variable1, 3, 0, string);  // (<variable>,<amount of digits we are going to use>,<amount of decimal digits>,<string name>)







  // We are going to print on the display everything that is dynamic on the loop, to refresh continuously:

  // Write to the display the Variable1 with left text alignment:
  ucg.setFont(ucg_font_inb16_mr);  // Set font
  ucg.setColor(0, 255, 255, 0);  // Set color (0,R,G,B)
  ucg.setColor(1, 0, 0, 0);  // Set color of text background (1,R,G,B)
  ucg.setPrintPos(9,81);  // Set position (x,y)
  ucg.print(Variable1);  // Print text or value

  // There is a problem when we go, for example, from 100 to 99 because it doesn't automatically write a background on
  // the last digit we are not longer refreshing. We need to check how many digits are and fill the space remaining.
  if(Variable1 < 10)  // If Variable1 is less than 10...
  {
    // Fill the other digit with background color:
    ucg.print(" ");
  }
  if(Variable1 < 100)  // If Variable1 is less than 100...
  {
    // Fill the other digit with background color:
    ucg.print(" ");
  }





  // Write to the display the string with right text alignment:
  ucg.setFont(ucg_font_inb16_mr);  // Set font
  ucg.setColor(0, 0, 255, 0);  // Set color (0,R,G,B)
  ucg.setColor(1, 0, 0, 0);  // Set color of text background (1,R,G,B)
  ucg.setPrintPos(76,81);  // Set position (x,y)
  ucg.print(string);  // Print text or value






}  // End of loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: you don't.

You only need to create a "custom character" on character-only displays (where you are actively programming a new character into the display's internal character set).

With a graphical display there is no "character" - only graphics.  The graphics library has fonts, which it then uses to convert text into graphics.

To display something that isn't in your currently selected font, just draw it. That could be from a bitmap graphic (there will be examples in your chosen graphics library) or using primitives, like circles and lines.

Comment: ah I see, my bad. I'll try my best to search up it then. I'm assuming I could just 'print' :) and it would display on the screen okay?

Comment: You could change the font that you are printing with. Make a custom font. No idea how you'd do that with your chosen library though. There may be examples and tutorials, or there may not...

Comment: I'm more than happy to use a different library, this one just seemed right on the mark for what I wanted. I think they have a whole list of fonts so I may just choose a pixel one and try my best from there. I know this is a different topic, but if my arduino is completely off a breadboard and linked up to the lcd, can I use a button on a breadboard and just put a wire to it or is it best to attach the arduino nano to the breadboard itself to make buttons work?

Comment: Makes no difference.

Comment: Thank you Majenko. If you're still here, on a 128 x 128 screen, which y and x axis would be the middle? I've tried a few but i think the text is still off screen? Having trouble with that

Comment: 64x64 is the middle of a 128x128 screen.

Comment: oh it's half. Ha I must be an idiot. Thank you, you've made my night so much easier! I shall leave you be =). Thanks once again